# Swallow touches, unless touching a child of my current layer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am writing a pause menu using a CCLayer. I need the layer to swallow touches so that you cannot press the layer below, however I also need to be able to use the buttons on the pause layer itself.

I can get the layer to swallow touches, but the menu won't work either.

Here is my code:

pauseLayer.m

```
#import "PauseLayer.h"

@implementation PauseLayer

@synthesize delegate;

+ (id) layerWithColor:(ccColor4B)color delegate:(id)_delegate
{
    return [[[self alloc] initWithColor:color delegate:_delegate] autorelease];
}

- (id) initWithColor:(ccColor4B)c delegate:(id)_delegate {
    self = [super initWithColor:c];
    if (self != nil) {

        NSLog(@"Init");
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
        CGSize wins = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

         delegate = _delegate;
         [self pauseDelegate];

        CCSprite * background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"pause_background.png"];

        [self addChild:background];

        CCMenuItemImage *resume = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"back_normal.png"
                                                         selectedImage:@"back_clicked.png"
                                                                target:self
                                                              selector:@selector(doResume:)];
        resume.tag = 10;
        CCMenu * menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:resume,nil];

        [menu setPosition:ccp(0,0)];

        [resume setPosition:ccp([background boundingBox].size.width/2,[background boundingBox].size.height/2)];

        [background addChild:menu];

        [background setPosition:ccp(wins.width/2,wins.height/2)];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)pauseDelegate
{
    NSLog(@"pause delegate");
    if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(pauseLayerDidPause)])
        [delegate pauseLayerDidPause];
}

-(void)doResume: (id)sender
{
    if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(pauseLayerDidUnpause)])
        [delegate pauseLayerDidUnpause];
    [self.parent removeChild:self cleanup:YES];
}

- (void)onEnter {
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:INT_MIN+1 swallowsTouches:YES];
    [super onEnter];
}

- (void)onExit {
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] removeDelegate:self];
    [super onExit];
}
- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    return YES;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why dont you just disable touches on the game layer?
like in the onEnter method disable the touches on the game layer..and onExit re enable them

something like

```
-onEnter{
gameLayer.isTouchEnabled=NO;
....
}
-onExit{
gameLater.isTouchEnabled=YES;
...
}
```

also you wont need CCTouchDispatcher

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything. :/
On my playscene, I call self.isTouchEnabled = NO; but it doesn't change anything. Right now I am just calling if(_pause)return; at the beginning of all my button methods, but that's pretty messy.

Comment: look in `CCTouchHandler.h` there are a few methods there that cover forwarding touches events to a delegate. that should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, the problem is the modal layer is swallowing events even if it's for the own children.

To solve this problem, you have to set the touch priority of the children even higher than  the modal layer itself.
In other words, set the menu's touch priority value below modal layer's.

There are two solutions.

1. Simply override "CCMenu::registerWithTouchDispatcher()" method and set the priority higher from the beginning.
2. Change menu's touch priority using "setPriority" method of the touchDispatcher or "setHandlerPriority" of menu itself.

To achieve second solution, you have to pay attention to the timing.
"CCMenu::registerWithTouchDispatcher()" is called somewhere AFTER "onEnter" and "onEnterTransitionDidFinish".

So, use "scheduleOnce" or something like that.

Sample codes.

```
- (id) initWithColor:(ccColor4B)c delegate:(id)_delegate {
   self = [super initWithColor:c];
   if (self != nil) {
         //your codes......   put CCMenu in instance

         [self scheduleOnce:@selector(setMenuPriority:) delay:0];
   }
   return self;
}

- (void) setMenuPriority (ccTime)dt {
   [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] setPriority:INT_MIN forDelegate:menu];
   //priority "INT_MIN" because you set the layer's priority to "INT_MIN+1".
}
```

PS: My english is not so good, so if there are loose sentences, correction  will be very pleased :)

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks!
I implemented registerWithTouchDispatcher in my popup menu layer. And inited it with `self.touchMode = kCCTouchesAllAtOnce; self.touchEnabled = YES;`. Then using that timer as you suggested (with the exact same priority values).

Comment: However I ran into more troubles later when adding yet another layer of the same characteristics on top. I hope someone could write something like a real working `CCLayerBlocking` class that would work in the same way as UIView; swallowing any touches to it unless the touches are on its children.

Comment: @Jonny. To evade the problem like you said, I usually store current layer's priority as member var. Then, when I need to overlap yet another layer, I pass that priority - 2 value as the parameter, (-2 because 1 for layer 1 for menu).

Comment: In addition, there might be the problem when you try to push and pop scene while using these layers. (Touch swallowing will not work at this situation) To evade this, put the ScheduleOnce in the onEnterTransitionDidFinish method. (To change the priority every time that transition occurs)

Answer (score 1):

**The problem is, that the layer/node hierarchy is *not* considered when propagating touches.
The touches are handed from the touch handler with the smallest `priority` value to the ones with the highest.**

The touches are not forwarded anymore, once one of the responders swallows the touch.

You can use an approach similar to `CCMenu`. `CCMenu` handles all touches and detects which `CCMenuItem`has been selected, based on the position of these items.

If you implement this the same way, you let your `PauseLayer` handle and swallow all touches and use a seperate mechanism to determine which child element in your `PauseLayer` has been selected.

### Example Implementation: CCMenu Subclass

I have implemented a solution in this repository:
https://github.com/Ben-G/MGWU-Widgets/tree/master/Projectfiles/Components/CCMenuBlocking

That component is a `CCMenu`Subclass that swallows all touches and does not forward them.

### Example Implementation: CCNode

Here is a more general solution of a `CCNode` that swallows touches and only forwards them to its own children:

https://github.com/Ben-G/MGWU-Widgets/blob/master/Projectfiles/Components/Popup/PopUp.m